# Django SQLite on Heroku doesn't recognize any of the changed models and throws a "relation doesn't exist" error

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, model, relation

I changed the name of several models on Django. Successfully ran makemigrations and migrate. I can interact with the SQLite directly as admin or through requests on localhost.

before changing the tables I had deployed to Heroku and it was working. when I changed the model names and pushed to Heroku (after successfully running on localhost) I get issues. When I login as admin to the site (on Heroku) I can interact with tables like User and Token, but not with the newly updated models. as soon as I click on them I get bellow error. when I click on add to these models, the columns appear but as soon as I hit save I get below error as well.

ProgrammingError at /admin/app_name/model_name/
relation "app_name_model_name" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "app_name_model_name"

I kept the Debug=True to see what's going on otherwise I get "500 Internal Server Error". I have added heroku's site as "ALLOWED_HOSTS".

When I was trying to make the migrations work, I had delete the files on the migration folder. not sure if there is a similar process on Heroku or if I'm missing something else?

By the way I have ran the migration commands using "heroku run bash" too. also, some of the models only had name changes, some had field updates too, but all of them throw the same error on Heroku.

Comment: "Django SQLite on Heroku"—this is a nonstarter. SQLite is not compatible with Heroku due to its [ephemeral filiesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). There is extensive documentation about this on Heroku's site, and there are several questions about it here.

Comment: there are limitations on SQLite but the point here is that it was working with Heroku but I'm getting this error after changing and migrating the models.

Comment: SQLite on Heroku causes _all kinds_ of problems, trivially including the exact error that you are seeing (e.g. if you don't migrate and commit changes to your database file, which is itself a _huge_ antipattern). You need to switch to a client-server database. SQLite is _not_ an option on Heroku.

Comment: "it was working with Heroku"—it was _not_. Your database would have been regularly reset to whatever state it had in the commit you had deployed. That includes data and structure.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the app entirely from Heroku and recreated. it's working now.